# Jumping frog problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Consider $n \ (>1)$ lotus leaves placed around a circle. A frog jumps from one leaf to another in the following manner. It starts from some selected leaf. From there, it skips one leaf in clockwise direction and jumps to the next one. Then it skips exactly $2$ leaves in clockwise direction and jumps to the next one. Then the frog skips $3$ in clockwise direction and so on. Suppose it turns out that if frog continues this way all leaves are visited by the frog. Show that $n$ cannot be odd.

My attempt,

Let frog be initially placed at leaf named $0$, and name the remaining leaves $1$, $2$ , $3$... $n - 1$  in clockwise direction.
After $k$ moves the frog will be on label number $0+(1+1)+(2+1)+\ ...\ + (k+1) = k (k+3)/2$.

Thus the question reduces to proving that there does not exist any $i$ such that $n = 2i+1$ and the congruence stated below is satisfied for all $t$ for some value of $k$:

$k(k+3)/2 \equiv t \,\pmod n, \;\; 0\leq t \lt n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Label the $n$ leaves as$\;0,...,n-1,\;$ordered counterclockwise from the starting leaf.

Let $f(k)$ be the position of the frog after $k$ steps.

\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;f(k) &= 2 + 3 + \cdots + (k+1) \;\;\text{mod}\;n\\[4pt]
&= {\small{\frac{k(k+3)}{2}}} \;\;\text{mod}\;n\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Since jump number $(n-1)$ skips $(n-1)$ leaves and lands on the next, it follows that for all $n$,

$$f(n-1) = f(n-2)$$

Next, suppose $n$ is odd.

Suppose $a,b$ are nonnegative integers such that $a \equiv b  \pmod n$.

\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;2(f(a) - f(b))&= 2\left({\small{\frac{a(a+3)}{2}}} - {\small{\frac{b(b+3)}{2}}}\right) \;\;\text{mod}\;n\\[4pt]
&=\bigl(a(a+3)\bigr) - \bigl(b(b+3)\bigr) \;\;\text{mod}\;n\\[4pt]
&=(a^2 + 3a) - (b^2 + 3b) \;\;\text{mod}\;n\\[4pt]
&=(a^2 - b^2) + (3a-3b) \;\;\text{mod}\;n\\[4pt]
&=(a-b)(a+b+3) \;\;\text{mod}\;n\\[4pt]
&=0\qquad\text{[since $a \equiv b  \pmod n$]}\\[12pt]
\implies\;2(f(a) - f(b)) &\equiv 0 \pmod n\\[4pt]
\implies\;f(a) - f(b) &\equiv 0 \pmod n\qquad\text{[since n is odd]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;f(a) &=  f(b)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

If follows that for odd $n$, the frog lands only on positions in the $n$-term sequence

$$f(0), f(1), f(2),...,f(n-1)$$

but then, since $f(n-1) = f(n-2)$, it follows that the frog lands only on positions in the $(n-1)$-term sequence

$$f(0), f(1), f(2),...,f(n-2)$$

hence the frog does not land on every leaf.

Thus, if the frog *does* land on every leaf, $n$ must be even.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: After $n$ turns the frog is back where it started, by your formula. (If $n$ is odd then $n\mid n(n+3)/2$.) It is also about to make a jump of length $2$ (mod $n$). So in the next set of $n$ jumps it will visit the same locations as the first $n$, in the same order, and this pattern will repeat. So it suffices to show that the frog doesn't visit all the locations in the first $n$ jumps.

Answer (score 0):

Since $n$ is odd $2$ is a unit in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Thus you can simplify your equation to:

$k(k+3)\equiv 2t \text{ mod }n$

As mentioned before $2$ is a unit thus for any $s\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ there is a $t\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ such that $2t\equiv s \text{ mod }n$. Therefore it suffices to show that there is a $s\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ such that for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$:

$k(k+3)\not\equiv s \text{ mod }n $

There are $n$ choices for $s$ and $k$ (namely $0,1,\dots,n-2,n-1$). If there are $k,k'\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ ($k\not\equiv k'$) such that $k(k+3)\equiv k'(k'+3)$ then there are at most $n-1$ different $s\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ such that:

$k(k+3)\equiv s \text{ mod }n $

If we choose $k=0$ and $k'=n-3$ we get $k(k+3)\equiv k'(k'+3)\equiv 0$. Therefore there has to be a choice for $s$ for which the equation above does not hold for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I'm  not  familiar with abstract algebra . I'll be giving an entrance exam to a college in a few days . I don't understand your proof. Kindly simplify.

Comment: As pointed out by @Especially Lime it suffices to show that the frog does not visit all locations in the first $n$ jumps. If the frog lands on the same location twice within the first $n$ jumps, then it visited at most $n-1$ locations. Then there hast to be one out of the $n$ locations that has not been visited. Thus it suffices to show that the frog lands on the starting location after $(n-3)$ and $n$ jumps.

Answer (score 0):

I will try providing, a very straightforward approach to solve the problem.

There are three parts that are used to prove the required claim (in the question):

### Prequisites:

But before, we begin, we number the lotus leaves as $1,2,3,...,n$ in the clockwise direction, with $1$ as that particular leaf, from where the frog begins the journey. After we establish this setting, we proceed to the next step below.

### Observation:

Here, we take, $n=7$ and proceed exactly what's specified in the problem. We find, the frog moves from leaf $1$( it's initial position ) to leaf $$1+2=3$$ (at it's first move) ,then to leaf $$1+2+3=6$$ (at it's third position or $2nd$ move ), and then to leaf $$1+2+3+4=10\pmod 7=3$$ (at it's third move) and then to leaf $$1+2+3+4+5=15\pmod 7=1$$ (at it's fourth move) and so on.

A pattern now, becomes apparent. The pattern is :
The frog goes to the $1+2+...+k=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\pmod 7$ th leaf at the $(k-1)th$ move.

With this pattern, in mind, we say:

For a number $n$, the frog moves to leaf number $$1+2+...+k=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\pmod n$$ th leaf at the $(k-1)th$ move. This will make things simpler for us.

### Proving the required claim:

After, we have observed the pattern then, we consider $n$ to be an arbitary (non-negative) odd number. Now, for a number $n$, the frog moves to leaf number $$1+2+...+k=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\pmod n$$ th leaf at the $(k-1)th$ move. So, at the $(n-1)$ th move, the frog jumps to leaf $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\pmod n.$  As $n$ is odd, we have $\frac{n+1}{2}$  even, and therefore, $$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\pmod n$$ is $$\begin{align}k_1n\pmod n=0=n\space\text{(as is the case here, for the leaf number 0 is equivalent to the leaf number n}\end{align}$$ ,where $k_1$ is an integer.

So, after $(n-1)$ th moves, the frog is at the $nth$ leaf  (i.e at the maximum numbered leaf) and in the next move i.e in the $nth$ move, the frog is at leaf $1.$  After $(n+1)$ moves, the frog, is at leaf $3$ and in the subsequent moves, the frog shifts from leaf $3\to 6\to  10\to ...\pmod n$.

We again observe, that after the $n-1$ th moves the subsequent moves are becoming periodic and exactly same as the move results, as to when the frog started it's journey (in other words, the results of the $1$st, $2$nd, $3$rd ,...,$(n-1)$th moves get repeated again, after the $(n-1)th$ move)  i.e from leaf $1\to 3\to 6\to....$ and so on.

So, we need to consider only, the first $(n-1)$ moves.

But the frog cannot traverse through all the leaves with just $(n-1)$ number of moves. It at least, needs $n$ moves to have all the leaves covered.

### Conclusion:

So, we have the claim proved that, " If $n$ is odd, the frog cannot traverse through all the $n$  leaves in the above described way."

I hope this solution is kept simple as it could  be. If you have any suggestions, please do let me know.